# Custom WooCommerce Checkout Form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, paypal, woocommerce

I'm trying to post form-data to the WooCommerce checkout and continue to PayPal using a form on a custom landing page.

The form uses jquery to add a product to the cart from the select box and when a user hits the checkout button after entering the billing information it should send the user to paypal and create the order as usual in WooCommerce.

I am using the standard form action below

```
<form id="msform" class="text-white" name="checkout" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And have made sure I included `<?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-pay' ); ?>`

It will not send the user to paypal and returns to the shopping cart with "We were unable to process your order, please try again."

Page Link : [Landing Page with Problem](https://www.koiler.com/offer)

JsFiddle : [preview of form code](https://jsfiddle.net/sb1y2on5/)

I've searched everywhere, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could authorize the payment with a Paypal gateway using a plugin like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-pro-payment-gateway/screenshots/).

Or you could use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) plugin to add a pay with Paypal button.

---

I haven't actually used either of these plugins, so I don't know how to integrate them.